# UITableViewCell text to equal an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am currently making code and I have saved an array full of textfields. The user will save the textfields to an array and then there will be a dictionary of arrays with all the different sets of textfield values. When they save the textfields to an array they will enter the name into another text field. How can I get the names of the array to load in a view controller so that when they click on a row the textfields associated with that array will load up? The table view, textfields, and textfield which names the array are all in separate views. I'm using interface builder if this helps.

```
NSArray *strings = @[self.normalWage.text, self.overtimeWage.text,
      self.mondayNormalTime.text, self.mondayOverTime.text, self.tuesdayNormalTime.text, 
      self.tuesdayOverTime.text, self.wednesdayNormalTime.text, 
      self.wednesdayOverTime.text, self.thursdayNormalTime.text, 
      self.thursdayOverTime.text, self.fridayNormalTime.text, self.fridayOverTime.text, 
      self.saturdayNormalTime.text, self.saturdayOverTime.text, 
      self.sundayNormalTime.text, self.sundayOverTime.text, self.bonusMoney.text];

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"myNumbers" : strings };

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:strings forKey:@"myNumbers"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: Could you write some code? You where not very clean in your explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a dictionary of arrays. I assume the dictionary keys are the array names.
Display the names of the arrays in a table view (you can get them using the `allKeys` property of the dictionary. You can sort the array by name for better readability. Once the user selects a cell, pass the text fields view controller the array, and in `viewDidLoad` fill the data from the array.